# Angular 8 Accordion with map not showing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, openstreetmap

I have the following project with Angular using bootstap accordion.
When the user click on the panel, the collapse panel will show a openstreet map but for some reason the map is not showing

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdbzhe

If i change the behavior to always show panel like so : class="collapse show" then the map is correctly initialized

Implementation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that it has a `display: none;` on the area where the canvas is supposed to be rendered.

Add an `map.updateSize()` to it after you've expanded your accordion and it works!

Have a look at this [working StackBlitz edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxio2d) I did.

Comment: great thank you it works! i was looking at implementing Subject but wasn't sure how to use it, very useful

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using for maps, but since you're not specifying the sizes anywhere I assume it autosizes the map element to fit the specified cotnainer.

Since your container's parent is set to display: none by the "collapse" class, the width and height will be unset, meaning the map will most probably have 0 width and 0 height.

I quickly checked the OL docs and it seems that you can use `this.map.updateSize();` to update the map sizing based on it's container size. How and when to call it is up to you - in current implementation I'd say try listening to style changes on your app-map component.

One side advice - instead of using "classic" bootstrap try using one of more angular-friendly frameworks, which will provide you with events and methods, making working with the code much easier in the long run.